# How to count bubbles deleted using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of bubbles that I can click and delete them with the javascript code I have written. I now am trying to figure out how to get it to count everytime i delete a bubble. Here is the html and javascript:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bubbles</title>
<link href="bubbles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bubbles.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/java.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!--background bubbles-->
<div id="b-blue" class="b" data-speed="1"></div>
<div id="b-green" class="b" data-speed="2"></div>
<div id="b-red" class="b" data-speed="4"></div>

<!--bubble text-->
<div id="bText">
    B<br />U<br />B<br />B<br />L<br />E<br />S<br />!
</div>

<!--bubble game-->
<div id="bubbleGame">
    <!-- <div class="bubble"></div> -->
</div>

<!--bubble score and reset-->
<div id="bottomCorner">
    <div id="reload">refresh...</div>
    <div id="score">0</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript for deleting bubbles

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#bubbleGame").on("click", ".bubble", function deleteb() {
$(this).remove();
})
})
```

Everytime I delete a bubble I want to add one to the "score" div. All the bubbles are in the "buublegame" div with the class ".bubble" I know I have used jquery but a way without would be preferable. Also to after clicking on the refresh button to restock the page with 20 bubbles.

Comment: Just add a variable that is incremented every time you call `deleteb()` and then update `#score` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#bubbleGame").on("click", ".bubble", function deleteb() {
    $(this).remove();
    $('#score').text( parseInt( $('#score').text() ) + 1 ); 
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/cL4LM/)

Answer (score 1):

How about a bit of closure practice:

```
function make_counter () {
    var i=0;
    return function () {
        i++;
        $('#score').text(i);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    counter = make_counter();
    $("#bubbleGame").on("click", ".bubble", function deleteb() {
        $(this).remove();
        counter();
    })
})
```

Demonstrated on a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/88cY6/).

#### edit

I went for a slightly different approach for the reset feature:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = {
        i: 0,
        incr: function () {
            this.i++;
            this.update();
        },
        reset: function () {
            this.i = 0;
            this.update();
        },
        update: function () {
            $('#score').text(this.i);
        }
    }

    $("#bubbleGame").on("click", ".bubble", function deleteb() {
        $(this).remove();
        counter.incr();
    });

    $("#reload").click(function () {        
        var i;
        $("#bubbleGame .bubble").remove();        
        for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
            $("#bubbleGame").append($("<div class='bubble'>"));
        }
        counter.reset();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle for this one](http://jsfiddle.net/9DXDR/)